# how to code <h1> tags with ghcjs

Tags: html, css, haskell, ghcjs

I have found the ghcjs documentation very limited.  Here is this basic HTML document.

```css
h1 { font-family: Helvetica; }

p {font-family: Helvetica; color: blue; }
```

```html
<h1>
Hello World
</h1>
<p>
This is my test document.
</p>
```

Is ghcjs just a combinator, basically typing the HTML as an output string?  Or does Haskell store a model of DOM somewhere?

My question is about all html tags and CSS, but maybe other tags have different features.

Comment: It is not clear what you are referring to. [GHCJS](https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs) is a Haskell-to-JavaScript compiler, and not e.g. a DOM manipualtion library.

Comment: @duplode if you are compiling to JavaScript presumably it is for the web? or for JS backend (such as node)

Comment: Yup -- arbitrary Haskell as input, JavaScript as output. A suitable JavaScript foreign function interface is provided so that communicating with the browser is possible for your code and/or the for libraries that require that.

Comment: @duplode can you point to where ghcjs communicates with the Browser? i am just trying to build a responsive website

Comment: Examples: [*js-dom-hello*](https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs-dom-hello); [*ghcjs-examples*](https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs-examples); [*react-flux-example*](https://github.com/agrafix/react-flux-example); [examples in the *react-flux* repository](https://bitbucket.org/wuzzeb/react-flux/src/tip/example/). API docs: [*ghcjs-dom-jsffi*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghcjs-dom-jsffi-0.7.0.1); [*react-flux*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/react-flux).

Comment: (Sorry for the above being just a list of links; I'm not familiar enough with GHCJS to tell for sure what would be the easiest path for a beginner.)

Comment: @duplode thank you so much for trying. ghcjs is very new -- and people are still figuring it out.  perhaps give someone else a turn?

Comment: @johnmangual ghcjs isn't new at all, and people have already figured it out. Are you perhaps trying to say "I'm very new to ghcjs, and am still trying to figure out how it works"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ghcjs` with the library `ghcjs-dom` to work with the `DOM` .

From the title of your question, `"how to code <h1> tags with ghcjs"`, and some of your comments, it looks like you are looking for a simple ghcjs/ghcjs-dom example that includes a few `HTML` tags.  This program will generate your `HTML` and respond to a click on the `h1` element:

```
import GHCJS.DOM (runWebGUI, webViewGetDomDocument)
import GHCJS.DOM.Document (getBody, createElement)
import GHCJS.DOM.Element (click, setInnerHTML)
import GHCJS.DOM.HTMLHeadingElement (castToHTMLHeadingElement)
import GHCJS.DOM.HTMLParagraphElement (castToHTMLParagraphElement)
import GHCJS.DOM.Node (appendChild)
import GHCJS.DOM.EventM (on)

main = runWebGUI $ \win -> do
        Just doc <- webViewGetDomDocument win
        Just body <- getBody doc

        Just h1 <- fmap castToHTMLHeadingElement <$> createElement doc (Just "h1")
        appendChild body $ Just h1
        setInnerHTML h1 (Just "Hello World")
        on h1 click $ setInnerHTML h1 (Just "Clicked")

        Just p <- fmap castToHTMLParagraphElement <$> createElement doc (Just "p")
        appendChild body $ Just p
        setInnerHTML p (Just "This is my test document.")

        return ()
```

This project: https://github.com/dc25/stackOverflow__how-to-code-h1-tags-with-ghcjs contains the above code.  Here is a link to a browser based demo:  https://dc25.github.io/stackOverflow__how-to-code-h1-tags-with-ghcjs/  The page changes if you click the "Hello World" header.

The `ghcjs` compiler output includes an `index.html` page.   Ghcjs will not overwrite that page if it already exists so you can safely edit it after it is created.  This allows you to directly include your `css` file.

Regarding documentation, this page: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/jsaddle-dom-0.4.0.1/docs/ contains useful links related to `ghcjs-dom` functionality.

Comment: @johnmangual It sounds like you're confused about what ghcjs _is_. Things are rarely useful until you understand what they are.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - as @Cubic already said - I think you are confused what GHCJS is.

GHCJS is a Compiler that lets you compile Haskell code to Javascript - rendering a simple page of html/css is not the task it was designed for. It is "Mit Kanonen auf Spatzen schießen" as we say in German - or shorter overkill.

So what would I use it for writing a front-end to a given haskell backend is really nice, you can share all your existing types and get all the maintainability and safety you have in the haskell eco-system.

But even if you don't have a haskell backend and you strife for novelty and good ideas - GHCJS might interest you, I myself am quite new to functional reactive programming, and having tried purescript(with pux) before now learning reflex/reflex-dom (my choice of front-end dsl) is a challenge for my brain and a delight - I know this paragraph is quite opinionated, but the abstractions presented in reflex seem right and seem to make clear some of the shortcomings of other functional reactive frameworks…

So how would one render the above in with the aforementioned libraries:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings   #-}
import           Reflex
import           Reflex.Dom

main :: IO ()
main = mainWidgetWithCss "h1 {font-family: Helvetica;} p {font-family: Helvetica; color: blue;}" $ do
  el "h1" $ text "Hello World!"
  el "p" $ text "This is my test document"
```

This is - as I said - overkill - you get a full run-time, a big chunk of js when some plain html/css would have sufficed. But for generating a complex UI in reusable components GHCJS might be the right choice.

The following is one of the more complex components I have yet written - it models a list of buttons that I can expand when clicking on the rightmost button, or shrink to the size of one of the other buttons (i use this for something like a "rate this X stars" but the stars can be arbitrary many).

```
listWidget :: MonadWidget t m => Int -> m (Event t Int)
listWidget n = leftmost <$> traverse button' [(-1)..(n+1)]

listWidget2 :: MonadWidget t m => m ()
listWidget2 = mdo
  clicked <- switchPromptlyDyn <$> widgetHold (listWidget (-1))
                                              (listWidget <$> clicked)
  return ()

button' :: (MonadWidget t m, Show a) => a -> m (Event t a)
button' val = (fmap $ const val) <$> button (text . pack $ show val)
```

### UPDATE:

The problem that plain Javascript has is scalability if you have a large amount of Javascript maintaining and changing code gets error prone and tedious because of the lacking type system and the dynamic nature. To remedy these problems there have come up a vast number of "compile-to-JS" languages - Haskell with GHCJS being one of them.

Comment: i am extremely confused about what it is and what it does.  i have misunderstood something essential about ghcjs

Comment: so why did you down-vote the answer - is it making it more unclear?

Comment: your answer makes clear that Haskell is not a good solution for front-end web development when there are much simpler tools

Comment: on the contrary - if you have a simple task use simple tools (html/css) but if you want a interactive, complex front end I would use it - though for production stuff you get a big chunk of js - that might be a problem if you are targetting mobile devices

Comment: these docs are atrocious

Comment: GHCJS is an open source project - if you are not happy with it, file bugs or even better try to expand the docs yourself, there are plenty of people happy to help, also go to the IRC and/or mailinglist. I think stackoverflow is not the right place to complain about lacking/bad documentation