# how to change <h1> tags with ghcjs-dom

Tags: css, haskell, ghcjs, ghcjs-dom

I have found the `ghcjs` and `ghcjs-dom` documentation very limited.  Here is this basic HTML document.

```css
h1 { font-family: Helvetica; }

p {font-family: Helvetica; color: blue; }
```

```html
<h1>
Hello World
</h1>
<p>
This is my test document.
</p>
```

I have read that `ghcjs` merely compiles Haskell to JavaScript.  If I want to populate the DOM tree even with this simple document, I need to the Foreign Function Interface (FFI) and possibly `ghcjs-dom`.

The irony of calling it the "*Foreign* Function Interface" is that JavaScript is usually considered "*native*" to the Browser.  So there is a tiny bit of terminology confusion there.

In this very simple example, maybe

Let's try a simple example of manipulating the DOM. I have a simple HTML document and I would like to 
* change the blue paragraph into a red one or 
* to switch back and forth once each second (between red and blue)

I don't see how the ghcjs set of tools will achieve harder tasks if it cannot even do these very basic test case and explain it.  Here is an issue I have raised on Github, with the conclusion that ghcjs lacks a good [on-boarding](https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/user-onboarding-best-practices-from-3-popular-mobile-apps/) process.

- https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs/issues/568

Comment: I am also offering to contribute to the Documentation of `ghcjs` starting with this simple question!  and maybe eventually some pull-requests

Comment: I feel your pain and surely you're right about the documentation situation, etc. but I'm not sure precisely what your question is. I googled "ghcjs hello world" and found this: https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs-dom-hello and this: https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs-examples perhaps you can clarify your question and then answer it yourself by consulting those examples, and that will help future newcomers

Comment: If you want to use ghcjs to create a client side web page that has the alternating red/blue behavior you describe, then reflex/reflex-dom is probably a better library choice than ghcjs-dom directly (reflex-dom depends on ghcjs-dom) .

Comment: @jberryman I am looking for [short, self-contained examples](http://sscce.org/) Can you adapt that hello world example to answer my question?  If I am asking on StackOverflow it is because I am not familiar with this library yet.  I found [this](https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs-examples/blob/master/ghcjs-hello/src/Main.hs) highly ambiguous example which basically just types the html page and uses Haskell to add various JavaScript features to it.

Comment: @DaveCompton is `ghcjs-dom` ever useful ?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, reflex-dom depends on ghcjs-dom so yes, ghcjs-dom is useful.  I'm sure there are other use cases.  I answered your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254610/how-to-code-h1-tags-with-ghcjs using ghcjs-dom rather than some higher level library ( eg reflex ) because it seemed like overkill to use a higher level library than necessary for that question.

Comment: @DaveCompton it is definitely not overkill.  These functions are not at all obvious.  I don't see the point to making new `ghcjs` learners suffer on the way to building a good web-site.

Comment: @johnmangual there's no conspiracy to make you suffer going on. In fact I see a lot of folks putting a lot of work into helping you out here and in your other question, in spite of your hostile and condescending tone. Working with very new projects where few examples exist can be challenging (we've all been there), but I think you'll find people more willing to help you if you can display some patience and show that you've put a little work in yourself.

Comment: @jberryman good documentation takes **a lot** of effort. Nobody *needs* to learn this or that library since there are so many other competing libraries, with a much larger and friendlier user base.  If you're too busy to make explain what you are working so hard on, then you should just say nothing at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a short self-contained example that uses [reflex-dom](https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex-dom) to do the red/blue color switching that you described. This is a modified version of the code that [epsilonhalbe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/630160/epsilonhalbe) included in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42262597/509928) to [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254610/how-to-code-h1-tags-with-ghcjs).

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-} 
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-} -- allows for local type declarations.
import Reflex
import Reflex.Dom
import Data.Text (Text, pack)
import Data.Map (Map)
import Data.Time.Clock (getCurrentTime)
import Control.Monad.Trans (liftIO)

webPage :: MonadWidget t m => m ()
webPage = do

  -- ticker Event fires once per second.
  ticker :: Event t TickInfo <- tickLossy 1.0 =<< liftIO getCurrentTime  

  -- counter Dynamic increases by one every second.
  counter :: Dynamic t Int <- foldDyn  (\_ n -> n+1) 0 ticker

  -- function to map from integer to red or blue style.
  let chooseColor :: Int -> (Map Text Text) 
      chooseColor n = "style" =: pack ("color: " ++ if (n `mod` 2) == 0 then "red" else "blue")

  -- redBlueStyle Dynamic changes each second.
  let redBlueStyle :: Dynamic t (Map Text Text) 
      redBlueStyle = fmap chooseColor counter

  -- insert an h1 elemnt.
  el "h1" $ text "Hello World!"

  -- insert a paragraph with Dynamic red blue style.
  elDynAttr "p" redBlueStyle $ text "This is my test document"

  return ()


css = "h1 {font-family: Helvetica;} p {font-family: Helvetica;}" 

main :: IO ()
main = mainWidgetWithCss css webPage
```

Of course, reflex-dom (along with reflex) is a higher level library than ghcjs-dom and it comes with its own set of concepts (Event, Dynamic, Behavior, etc) that you need to get comfortable with.

The example works by creating a Dynamic Map that specifies a style that alternates from red to blue each second and using that Dynamic Map to style an element.

For clarity's sake, this example contains some type declarations that are not strictly required.

This project: https://github.com/dc25/stackOverflow__how-to-change-h1-tags-with-ghcjs-dom contains the above code. Here is a link to a browser based demo: https://dc25.github.io/stackOverflow__how-to-change-h1-tags-with-ghcjs-dom/